# how to list each word once? ignore the non-alphabetic characters

Tags: linux, bash

the following text for the example,
Unix was born in 1969 out of the mind of a computer scientist at Bell
Laboratories, Ken Thompson. Unix began its life on a scavenged PDP-7 minicomputer

```
 tr -cs "[:alpha:]" "\n" < file | sort -u
```

And the result seems to be fine, but I found a problem ,that "PDP-7" in the original text becomes "PDP" , I'm not sure whether I should add some more arguments?

Comment: this seems like a h/w question.

Comment: I'm not sure,  learn linux and shell scripts only 2 weeks

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: when you say "nothing works", you're missing the whole point of StackOverflow. We want to help you fix your **code**, but if you don't include any *code*, we can't help  you fix it, and your Q is likely to be voted closed for multiple reasons. Read the `how to ask a good Q` as mentioned above, then go forth and sin no more ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Ok,I'm sorry for that. I've been touched this website for only several days, maybe I ignore some important rules, and I will close my Q

Comment: Does 'non-alphebetic characters' exclude numbers too?  You have shown your input, which is a good start, but, as others have pointed out, you need to provide what you have tried and also I would suggest an example of the output.  To make it not so large, maybe reduce your input to only a line or two and include both items to be excluded and included so those assisting have an idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: ok I'll reduce my input

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you're asking (not that that was a well-formed question):

```
sed -r  's/[[:space:]]/\n/g' unix | sed -r 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g' | sort -u
1960s
1962
1969
a
actual
almost
also
an
and
at
barely
batch
beasts
been
Bell
born
But
by
computer
computing
concept
deployment
earlier
else
everywhere
experience
experimental
first
for
had
him
in
inventor
it
John
Ken
Laboratories
language
late
Lisp
McCarthy
mind
Multics
novel
of
on
one
operating
out
primitive
project
researcher
rule
scientist
seven
speculations
spoiled
still
systems
temperamental
ten
that
the
Thompson
timesharing
Unix
uttered
was
were
which
years
```

Comment: Since the question has been since heavily modified my solution no longer matches ...  should I delete my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Remember to use sort before using uniq -u, such as:

```
sort | uniq -u
```

And if you want to keep only letters, you can also pipe in the following:

```
sed "s/[[:digit:].-]//g"
```

Hope that helps. Having an example of your code/list would be great.

Comment: Hi,I tried your code ,but I think it has a small question. The word 'PDP-7' will become PDP and 1968s will become s , in my definition, I want the text only    output the words which are  sequences of severals alphabetic characters

Comment: of course ,tr -cs "[:alpha:]" "\n" I use it and has the same problem.